# Expressing a reason for an action?

Tags: sentence-structure, idiomaticity

In English, I might say “I am making a meal for my family.” I might also say “I am locking the doors for peace of mind.” Syntactically, this is the same construction as in the first, which makes me view it as almost idiomatic and therefore not the best template for expressing such ideas in German.

What are the most natural ways in German to indicate the purpose motivating an action? More examples in English:

> I am drinking this water **to** quench my thirst.
>
> **Since** I am thirsty, I am drinking this water.
>
> I am drinking this water **because** I am thirsty.
>
> I am drinking this water **for** its thirst-quenching properties.

I’ve put words in bold which tempt me to translate them literally. I do not trust them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up things. Your first two examples are very different from the five latter ones.

> I am making a meal for my family

*Ich mache (gerade) Essen für meine Familie.*

That's a straight main clause, as *for my family* is preposition + object. In German you could also write

*Ich mache (gerade) meiner Famile Essen.*

which uses the dative case for *meine Familie* to make it the indirect object. (*Essen* is the direct object in both sentences.)

> I am locking the doors for peace of mind.

is similar, though you give a *reason*. That's what you asked for.

*Ich schließe die Tür für meinen Seelenfrieden ab.*

*Ich schließe die Tür zu meine**m** Seelenfrieden ab.*

This works exactly as the English sentence, as *Seelenfrieden* is a fixed expression as *peace of mind* is in English. Note *Seelenfrieden* it's usually used with a possesive pronoun instead of a simple article.

Again, *für meinen Seelenfrieden* is preposition + object. Also *zu meinem Seelenfrieden*, but *zu* takes a dative object.

---

Now the latter five sentences. They are more complicated.

> I am drinking this water to quench my thirst.

Ich trinke dieses Wasser, **um** meinen Durst **zu** stillen.

German uses a so called *final clause* in this case. Typical marker of these constructions is *um … zu + infinitive* which means the same as English *to + infinitive*. The comma is not optional though many Germans forget to put it in.

> Since I am thirsty, I am drinking this water.

*Da ich durstig bin, trinke ich dieses Wasser.*

Subordinate clause with *da* in front, main clause follows. English concatenates two main clauses here, which is also possible in German but isn't straightforward.

*Ich bin durstig, **daher** trinke ich dieses Wasser*

See how the *since* (*da*, *daher*) moves to the second main clause in German.

> I am drinking this water because I am thirsty.

*Ich trinke dieses Wasser, weil ich durstig bin.*

Main clause in front, subordinate clause with *weil* follows.

> I am drinking this water for its thirst-quenching properties.

*Ich trinke dieses Wasser **wegen** seiner durststillenden Eigenschaften.*

This one uses *wegen + genitive object*. Again, this is pretty straightforward, as *wegen seiner* is a drop-in for English *for its*.

Comment: Now _that's_ what I'm talking about! This is gold to me, thank you.
(Unfortunately, I can't upvote yet.)

Comment: "Ich schließe die Tür zu meinem Seelenfrieden ab" could be mis-understood as if the *Seelenfrieden* had a door that could be locked. (like in "Ich schliesse die Tür zur Garage ab")

Comment: True. But I don't think anyone would be such a poet when closing doors.

Comment: Language is so much fun. @tofro, thank you for pointing this out (even if it would be a stretch).